# Issue on assigning base image, small_image, Thumbnail_image programatically using csv?

Tags: magento2.4, product-images, media-images, product-import

I have created a php file to assign the **base_image, small_image, Thumbnail_image** using below script.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$csv = "local_alain.csv";
if (!empty($argv) && sizeof($argv) > 1) { $csv = $argv[1]; }
if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($num < 1) { continue;}
    $sku = explode(',',trim($data[0])); 
    $imagePath = $sku[1];
    try {
        $product = $productRepository->get($sku[0]);
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        $product->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage()."</br>";
        continue;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

My csv file( in this csv file i am updating the actual image path of the image which want to be assigned as **base_image, small_image, Thumbnail_image**, These images are already uploaded to products. **This image paths are getting from the product export csv**)

```
Beauty Care Product,/1/6/16-02-08651_1.jpeg
Vitamin Products,/1/6/16-02-05659_1.jpeg
Sports Nutrition Product,/1/6/16-02-05659_1_1.jpege
```

But i am getting an error of

> Path "/1/6/16-02-05659_1_1.jpeg" cannot be used with directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/alain-ecom/pub/media/"

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here my issue was image path. I have added the image path as `/1/6/16-02-05659_1_1.jpeg`. But actually it should be from the **pub/catalog/product**.

So i updated my script as below.

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('catalog/product'.$imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```